# Specific closure/scoping issue in jQuery

Tags: jquery, closures

I so often run into this pattern.
Can someone please give me a canonical way of only getting image1 once - if you look at example two, it works - but I fail to understand why. An explanation of this specific situation is appreciated, I have read the closure stuff on the net :)

Initial code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#prev, #next").click(function() {
    var mainImage = $("#image1");
    if (mainImage.css("visibility")=="hidden") {
      $(mainImage.css("visibility","visible");
      return;
    }
    var currentNumber = parseInt(mainImage.attr("src").split('gallery/')[1]); 
    var newNumber = ($(this).attr("id")=="next")?currentNumber+1:currentNumber-1;
    var testImage = new Image();
    testImage.onload=function() {
      var img = $("#image1");
      img.attr("src",this.src);
      img.css("visibility","visible");   
    }
    testImage.onerror=function() {
      $("#image1").css("visibility","hidden");   
    }
    testImage.src="gallery/"+newNumber+".jpg";
    return false;
  });
});
```

---

Attempting a closure - why does it work - or is this just a scoping issue?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#prev, #next").click(function() {
    var mainImage = $("#image1"); // this should be local to the click function
    if (mainImage.css("visibility")=="hidden") {
      $(mainImage.css("visibility","visible");
      return;
    }
    var currentNumber = parseInt(mainImage.attr("src").split('gallery/')[1]); 
    var newNumber = ($(this).attr("id")=="next")?currentNumber+1:currentNumber-1;
    var testImage = new Image();
    testImage.onload=function() {
      mainImage.attr("src",this.src); // how come mainImage is available here?
      mainImage.css("visibility","visible");   
    }
    testImage.onerror=function() {
      mainImage.css("visibility","hidden");// how come mainImage is available here?
    }
    testImage.src="gallery/"+newNumber+".jpg";
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, vars live in the scope of the function where it has been defined, **and the 'subfunctions' (local functions) inside this function**.

For example:

```
function fun1(){
   var var1 = "Defined in fun1. ";
   function fun2(){
      var var2 = "Defined in fun2. ";
      alert(var1); //Alerts "Defined in fun1 "
      function fun3(){
          alert(var1 + var2); //Alerts "Defined in fun1. Defined in fun2";
      }
   }
   alert(var2); //Alerts 'undefined' (fun1 doesn't know var2 exists)
}
```

And the same is happening in your code. Your variable `mainImage` 'lives' in every local function. Don't forget that binded functions are also local functions, even if they don't have name or are declared differently.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: They are the same clowns with distinct nicknames hehe

Answer (score 1):

This is how JavaScript scoping works. Take a look at the following:

```
var func1 = function(){
    console.log(i + 2);
};

var myFunc = function(){
    var i = 1;
    var func2 = function(){
        console.log(i + 2);
    };
    func2(); // output 3
    func1(); // ReferenceError: i is not defined
};
```

Answer (score 0):

mainImage is defined with var so it becomes global for all functions

Comment: ??? if I do NOT use var, it becomes a global windows var. but WITH var, it normally stays local to the function it is defined in